# Why nothing is inserted in the table even if it is related to sql and laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created a modal using Bootstrap, to add a new row into table.
I don't know why and how doesn't work.

This is table_edit.blade.php MODAL:

```
<div id="formModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Adaugare Rolete</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <span id="form_result"></span>
         <form method="post" id="sample_form" class="form-horizontal" action ="{{route('tabledit.store')}}">
          @csrf
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" >ProdusID : </label>
            <div class="col-md">
             <input type="text" name="ProdusID" id="ProdusID" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Denumire : </label>
            <div class="col-md">
             <input type="text" name="Denumire" id="Denumire" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" >Cant1 : </label>
            <div class="col-md">
             <input type="text" name="Cant1" id="Cant1" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           </div>
           
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" >Cant2 : </label>
            <div class="col-md">
             <input type="text" name="Cant2" id="Cant2" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           </div>
           
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" >Cant3 : </label>
            <div class="col-md">
             <input type="text" name="Cant3" id="Cant3" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           </div>
           
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" >Cant4 : </label>
            <div class="col-md">
             <input type="text" name="Cant4" id="Cant4" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           </div>
           
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" >Data : </label>
            <div class="col-md">
             <input type="date" name="Data" id="Data" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           </div>
           
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" >Pret Intrare : </label>
            <div class="col-md">
             <input type="text" name="Pret_Intrare" id="Pret_Intrare" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           </div>
           
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" >Pret Iesire : </label>
            <div class="col-md">
             <input type="text" name="Pret_Iesire" id="Pret_Iesire" class="form-control" />
            </div>
           </div>
          
                <br />
                <div class="form-group" align="center">
                 <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="Add" />
                 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />
                 <input type="submit" name="action_button" id="action_button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Add" />
                </div>
         </form>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here we can see I do an easy html bootstrap, it's oke, it's work, but affter, maybe in Controller it's the problem.

This is Controller:

```
   public function store(Request $request){
        $rules = array(
            'ProdusID'  => 'required',
            'Denumire' => 'required',
            'Cant1' => 'required',
            'Cant2' => 'required',
            'Cant3' => 'required',
            'Cant4' => 'required',
            'Data' => 'required',
            'Pret_Intrare'  => 'required',
            'Pret_Iesire' => 'required'  
        );   
   
         $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        
        if($error->fails()){
            return response()->json(['errors' => $error->errors()->all()]);
        }

        
        $form_data = array(
            'ProdusID'  =>  $request->ProdusID,
            'Denumire' =>  $request->Denumire,
            'Cant1' =>  $request->Cant1,
            'Cant2' =>  $request->Cant2,
            'Cant3' =>  $request->Cant3,
            'Cant4' =>  $request->Cant4,
            'Data' =>  $request->Data,
            'Pret_Intrare'  =>  $request->Pret_Intrare,
            'Pret_Iesire' =>  $request->Pret_Iesire
        );
  
        Rolete::create($form_data);
        
        return response()->json(['succes' => 'Data Added successfully.']);
   }
```

And web:

```
Route::post('tabledit/store', 'TableditControllerRolete@store')->name('tabledit.store');
```

This is an image with modal
[image]

(!) UPDATE: I don't have any error, but he doesn't adding into table.

Comment: The problem is your form is method is POST and route is registered as GET. 

Recommended to use POST:


Route::post('tabledit/store', 'TableditControllerRolete@store')->name('tabledit.store');

Also your route is not set for the form action.

Comment: I upload with new route and set from action but nothing..

Comment: Laravel logs and browser request inspector is your best friend. By default Laravel writes logs to storage/logs/laravel.log see if there any error appearing when you make the request. There is always a response so check your browser inspector. Here is a link that can help you to learn about network activity inspection https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/

Answer (score -2):

your form don't have an action attribute. you should fix that line with this:

```html
<form method="post" id="sample_form" class="form-horizontal" action ="{{route('tabledit.store'}}">
```